# How to apply a html conditionally on Orchard CMS

Tags: .net, content-management-system, orchardcms

My site has 3 Menus Navigation but I need that each one use different html renderization.

I need some orientation about what can I use to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Enable shape tracing and widget alternates on your dev site, create alternates as needed and edit their cshtml files to get the desired result, then disable shape tracing.